# Mounting via /etc/fstab on OS X, but umount deletes mount point?

Tags: macos, filesystem

*The below is for OS X 10.11.x (El Capitan)*

I've successfully been able to mount an AFP share (from my NAS) using the commands

```
mkdir /Volumes/V
mount -t afp afp://username:password@LANIP/v /Volumes/V
```

Works like a charm.  I can also add this to my /etc/fstab:

```
# device                         mount_point  filesystem  options                     freq  passno
afp://username:password@LANIP/v  /Volumes/V   afp         nodev,nosuid,automounted    0     0
```

So when I issue `mount -a`, things work as expected.

However, if I unmount, either via `umount /Volumes/V` or `diskutil umount /Volumes/V`, the umount command unmounts (good), and deletes `/Volumes/V` (bad?).  Then when I try to mount again, I get an error.

Here is an exact set of steps:

```
sh-3.2# mkdir /Volumes/V
sh-3.2# mount -a
sh-3.2# umount /Volumes/V
sh-3.2# mount -a
mount: realpath /Volumes/V: No such file or directory
sh-3.2#
```

This seems a bit chicken-and-egg: I can't mount the mount point without creating it, but when I create it and later unmount it (e.g. at shutdown) it blows itself away.

Is there some place I can create `/Volumes/V` before `/etc/fstab` is acted upon by automount?  I found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/385980/create-directory-before-binding-via-etc-fstab) but it refers to `/etc/init.d`, which doesn't seem to be on Mac OS X (although there is an `/etc/mach_init.d` which is empty at the moment).

Comment: For the directory to be automatically created, you have to use `automount`  See, `man automount` for more details.

Comment: @Allan, is it a straight call to `automount`?  When I do that, I get the same error.  I'm not sure how to update the `/etc/auto_master`, because looking at it, `/etc/auto_master` looks to call `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: The minus in front of fstab (`-fstab`) tells it NOT to look in fstab.  You can have direct or indirect mount points specified.  I'm away from my Mac at the moment, so I am doing this all from memory, but have a look at this article:  https://useyourloaf.com/blog/using-the-mac-os-x-automounter/